# Code to write to google datastore broke after migration to HRD

Tags: google-app-engine

The below code was working perfectly fine on master-slave replication datastore and broke after we moved to HRD today. The exception I see is just

```
E 2012-09-19 21:59:13.603
vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode writeToGoogleStore: Exception in finally of execute of writeToGoogleStore
E 2012-09-19 21:59:13.603
vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode writeToGoogleStore: Exception class is :java.io.IOException
E 2012-09-19 21:59:13.603
vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.server.common.CommonServiceCode writeToGoogleStore: Exception is :null
```

Code

```
try {

        log.info("Starting google storage");
        // Get the file service
        FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
        GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
                .setBucket(bucketName).setKey(key).setAcl("public-read")
                .setMimeType("text/html");

        // Create your object
        AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService
                .createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());

        // Open a channel for writing
        boolean lockForWrite = true;
        FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(
                writableFile, lockForWrite);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(writeChannel,
                "UTF8"));
        out.println(emailMsgTxt);
        out.close();
        writeChannel.closeFinally();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.severe("Exception in finally of execute of writeToGoogleStore");
        log.severe("Exception class is :" + e.getClass().getName());
        log.severe("Exception is :" + e.getMessage());
        return "failed";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to HR also means you've got a new app name and service account name. You'll probably need to add the new account to the ACL of that storage bucket.

Comment: oh is it.. i dont even remember where if really i added any app id specific details anywhere.